# How to hide a Component, When I click a text, and that text belongs to another component in Angular

Tags: angular

Assume that I have a component name is flightreview, In that flightreview component I have some text: Flight on Saturday, January 26th, 2019 from BLR to DXB Total duration: 9 h 55 m Details.
Under the text of Flight on Saturday, January 26th, 2019 from BLR to DXB Total duration: 9 h 55 m, I have another component name is app-alltickets

By default app-alltickets Component is showing now, but when someone clicks a text that belongs to flightreview, component, then the  component has to hide.
How to achieve this task in Angular.

I am using the component's name exactly that's why it is only showing some errors if you don't understand please go through the code.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-9">
      <app-flightreview></app-flightreview>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <app-faredetails></app-faredetails>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="row pt-5">
  <div class="col-12">
    <section>
      <div class="card clickable">
        <div class="card-header custom onClick='hide()'">
          Review Your Flight Details
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <section>
      <div class="card clickable">
        <div class="card-header flightDetails">
          <span class='iconcustom'><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
          Flight on Saturday, January 26th 2019 from BLR to DXB Total duration: 9 h 55 m
          <app-alltickets></app-alltickets>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case I'd recommend simple input property component interaction [hidden]="hidden".

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

A possible global solution without parent-child interaction could be to provide an observable hide$ provided by a shared service. So you can next(true) in component A on click and apply the hide notification in component B